# pause and resume message driven beans - programatically

Tags: java, jms, java-ee-6

I have a requirement where, I need to expose a REST interface, which will suspend a MDB from consuming messages from the JMS Queue.

similarly, another REST interface to resume the MDB.

I am constrained to the following

A) Use Java EE 6 Spec
B) Use Websphere 8.5.5.5, I can use Glassfish for proof of concepts

I am open to using MBean interface too as an alternate solution, if its not possible to do the above.

Comment: Would simply sending a "ignore all incoming messages from now on until message x arrives" to the queue not work? Ok, might be crude ;-)

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz, as long it works I am fine, even if it is crude. The I guess I need to do the following  (A) send this 'Control' message with the highest prioirty    (B) what I do not know is this  : Once the MDB receives this 'Control' message - How can it **self** regulate itself. any sample code would be great.  Btw is there JMS API to support this kind of behaviour.  -thank you